# Fixing broken django module that was installed from pip, where is the code?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have been trying to use the django-visits module, though I seem to not even get this to run cause the minute I follow the instructions for just adding it to my application here:

https://bitbucket.org/jespino/django-visits/src/c3ac83b91969?at=default

It gives me an error when I try to run server:

```
ERRORS:
 visits.Visit.ip_address: (fields.E900) IPAddressField has been removed 
  except for support in historical migrations.
   HINT: Use GenericIPAddressField instead.
```

Their hint was helpful enough, but I have no idea where pip instaleld my django-visits to where I can change the model code of this module to fix the IPAdressField

Am I approaching solving this error wrong?  Should I not be looking for the original code that was installed somewhere on my machine? Do I need to somehow install this from source and not use Pip since I have to change the models.py in this module?

(I am trying to make this work on my OS X machine but ultimately will need to get this to work on CentOS box). Also the database is postgres/postgis

Comment: I would not edit the code that pip installed for you. You should fork the project, fix it, and install it from your source

Comment: Thank you did this, now having a heck of a time getting setuptools to install this from source.   Opening a new Question on this front.